# 1 is a generator for the set of integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm reading a text here that explains that the members of a cyclic group would be:

$x^{-2}, x^{-1}, x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3,...$

It goes on to say that,

> The basic element *x* is considered to be the *generator* of the group, since all other members of the group are derived from it.  It is also referred to as a *primitive element* of the group.

Here's the part that sounds wrong to me:

> Integers could be considered a cyclic group, with 1 being the primitive element (the generator).  All integers can be expressed as a power of 1 in this group.

Would this not be saying that all integers can be represented with the form $1^x$ where x is a member of the set of integers?

Comment: This is a common confusion, stemming from the fact that both things called "multiplication" and things called "addition" may give rise to a group structure. Thus, the _general_ language will have a hard time representing both at the same time.

Comment: This is true with binary operation being addition.  It isn't true under multiplication.  But the notation $1^n=1*1*1 ....$ does *require* that $*$ means multiplication.  If $*$ means addition $1^n=n\circ 1=1+1+1.... =1*1*1*...... $

Comment: @fleablod, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Does NOT require.... sigh....

Comment: I got it the first time. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a*b = a+b $ then $a^3=a*a*a=a+a+a=3\times a $ and therefore, yes, it *would* be saying $\mathbb Z =\{1^x|x\in\mathbb Z\} =\{x\times 1|x\in \mathbb Z\} $.  It *would* be saying that and it would be correct.

But that would be inconsistent notation.  We usually use $*, a^n, 1=identity $ for groups even though $*$ doesn't need to mean "multiplication" and 1 doesn't need to be the number 1.  To avoid confusion we sometimes use $+,n\circ a,0=identity $.  This doesn't always mean addition either be we tend to use it when we do mean "addition".

But yes $( \mathbb Z, +)= <1,+> = \{n\circ 1\} $ is how we'd usually notation the statement that the integers is a cyclic group *under addition* generated by $1$.

Comment: So, then, it sounds as though the real issue is that he fails to indicate which operation would be used in this case...  Bear in mind that this is a text for non-math majors.

Comment: It assumes it is clear that the operation is addition.  Whether they are correct in that assumption I'll leave to you judgement.  But all groups have an associated operation and there is no need to assume it is multiplication.

Comment: to follow from what you just stated, would it be equally true that there is no need to assume that it is addition?

Comment: By the way.  If p is prime then <p,x>=all the positive an negative powers of p, and <1,+> = all the integers are isomorphic and equivalent groups.

Comment: No, I guess not.  But it is hard to imagine what else it could be.  The integers are closed under addition and that should be well known.  They are not closed under multiplication.  I would assume that if I say "the integers are a group" it'd have to be addition.  I'd assume if I said "the rationals are a group" people would assume I meant under multiplication and if I meant under addition (which they are) I'd specify that.  But yes, you are correct.  It should be specified.

Answer (score 3):

The operation in that group is addition. So it should be "all integers are of the form $\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_x$."

Comment: Since the group of integers is closed under multiplication, would it be reasonable to suggest that the author specifies which operation must be applied?  It's true that this is a fairly simple case, I suppose, but imagine we were talking about less obvious values.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It is not a group under multiplication since it does not contain inverses.

Comment: forgive my rudimentary knowledge.. I stopped after Calc 3... :)  Are you saying that this would imply that addition *must* be the operation that is implied, so there's no need to state it?

Comment: Integers do *not* have inverses under multiplication so they are not a group under multiplication.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer No worries, we all confront these questions at some point in our lives. I think they expected readers would be able to fill in the blank. By the way, if you are doing arithmetic [modulo $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) where $p$ is prime, then the integers (modulo $p$) do form a group under multiplication.

Comment: That would depend on my mood.  But generally not.  $a^n $ is an abstraction so I wouldn't have any issue with $a^n=n\cdot a $ but I would have issue with "$1\ne identity $".  But I wouldn't have problems shifting gears from $<a,*>=\{a^n\} $ to $<a,+>=\{a\cdot n\} $.  And from there $1=generator\ne identity $ wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A generator in a cyclic group is the element which generates the other elements of the group. In your case, integers under addition, that means that the element 1 generates the rest of the elements of the group.

It also satisfies some properties: existence of inverse, identity element, commutativity, closure under addition and associativity.

When you are working with multiplicative integers mod p then the definition of a generator is the same: an element that generates the whole group, its order being $\phi(n)$. Then it receives the name primitive-root mod n, but generator is still valid.

Comment: Actually, it is clear from the op that the book did not mean modulo but meant all integers.

Comment: @fleablood: Fixed the sentence "in your case integers mod n". Btw I find helpful the rest of the explanation since it can be useful for anyone who's studying cyclic groups and multiplicative integers mod n. Thanks for pointing my error out.